# why am i outputting the wrong string at the same time as the right

Tags: python, string

i am taking a beginners programming class in python and we have just got to strings. our first assignment is to access a text file and return the lines that contain a specified letter. when i do this however, i get one line that is correct, and one that is completely wrong

```
text = open('some.txt')
def countLine(text):
q = 0 
for c in text:
    return(c)

def countLetterFile(char):
    for f in countLine(text):
        if f == char:
            print(countLine(text))
        else:
            pass
countLetterFile('w')
```

it should print 'words make up other words'
'words make sentences'
and 'I have MS word'

instead i get this

```
This is a line

words make sentences
```

Comment: Check your indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem with your code. In the countLine function, you are going through the characters of the line. You are using this function to check and again this function to print. You just need to print text instead of countLine(text).

Alternatively, you can do the following:

```
if char in text:
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as a function returns something with the `return` statement, it breaks.

Why not just check if the letter is in the line?

```
def countLetterFile(char):
    for f in text:
        if char in f:
            print(f)
```

Comment: that solves my problem, but why is it returning the wrong string?

Comment: @user2330498 I think that's because you're calling `countLine(text)` while printing. So it prints the next line instead of the current line